# Specify which node should turn off

Tags: omnet++

I'm trying to simulate a sensor network in Castalia, where each radio works with a different duty cycle. I'm controlling the radio by the application, through the commands `toRadioLayer(createRadioCommand(SET_STATE,SLEEP))` to turn off and `toNetworkLayer(createRadioCommand(SET_STATE,RX))` to turn on. However, as each radio has its own schedule, I need to send this command to a specific radio. Is it possible to define for which node these commands, or another if it exists, are executed?

Answer (score 0):

Every node has its own application module. So when the application sends the commands you describe, these go to the radio module of the same node. So if you need different nodes to use different duty cycles, then you'd have to build it in the application to behave differently according to whatever conditions you have in mind. One very simple way is to choose randomly the duty cycle (so each application module will have a different duty cycle).

If you want application modules to communicate across nodes, then there is no magic way for this. You'll have to establish communication via data packets.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, but how can I define the node (nodeID) to which I'm sending the command? I didn't find a reference in the manual. Poderi gives me a hypothetical example. Please kindly ask for your help.

Comment: It seems to me that you have not fully grasped the architecture of Castalia. Reading the Chapter 2 of the User's manual can probably help you. As I write in the answer, when you send a command from the application to the Radio, it all happens in the same node. You can not send a command to another node, the model does not work this way.